# Need to make this more Ruby-like

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby and I seem to be comfortable using while loops. But I would like to simplify my code by possibly using the 'each' method. How would I do this for this particular block of code?

```
sum_array = []
i = 0
while i < array.length - 1
    j = i + 1
    while j < array.length
        sum = array[i] + array[j]
        if sum != 0
            sum_array << sum
        end 
        j += 1
    end
    i += 1
end
```

Comment: A short explanation or an example would be fine. Even when your code is not that complex it is hard to read. I guess you get more answers when you add more pieces of information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sum_array = array.combination(2).map{|n, m| n + m}.reject(&:zero?)
```

Comment: That is so much better! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
array = (1..10).to_a # test array [1,2,3,4,....10]
sum_array = []
(0...array.length).each do |i| # from 0 to array.length-1
  (i+1...array.length).each do |j| # from i+1 to array.length-1
    sum = array[i] + array[j]
    sum_array << sum unless sum == 0 # brief condition
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_array(input)
  [].tap do |sums|
    input.each_with_index do |x, index|
      tail = input[index.next..-1]
      tail.each do |y| 
        sum = x + y
        sums << sum unless sum.zero?
      end
    end
  end
end

puts sum_array([1,2,0,0])
# => [3,1,1,2,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
sum_array = []
array.each_index do |i| 
  sum_array += (i+1...array.length).collect { |j| array[i] + array[j] }
end
sum_array.reject!(&:zero?)
```

Comment: This always returns an empty `sum_array`. `(i+1..-1).collect` is not doing anything for a decreasing range (calling `.to_a` on it yields the empty Array as well).

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers Had something with `array[i+1..-1]` first.